# How to update asp.net server with element value?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a site with many textboxes, I need to get their value from the page to a database.  I have written a simple little function in jQuery that iterates through all the textboxes much easier than doing it with vb.net.  I am comfortable interfacing with the database directly in vb.net.  I have tried many ways to get the`Label1`value to persist after calling the function so that I can use vb to parse the text and update the database accordingly.  As I'm new to asp.net I'm sure I'm missing some basic in the postback process and/or understanding.  Your help is appreciated.

```
 $("#Button1").click(function () {  
    var str ="DBN;", shape;
    $('.test').each(function () {
        Num = $(this).val();
        if (Num > 0) {
            shape = $(this).attr("name");
            str += shape + "~" + Num + ","
        }; /// end if 
    });/// end each
    $('#Label1').text(str);
    //event.preventDefault();
});/// end function
```

Comment: Why not just use `$('#myForm').serialize()` to get the values and ajax to send the data to the backend?

Comment: @Kstro21, no experience with ajax, can you send me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i recall correctly the values of labels doesn't persist when modified clientside. Try putting them in hidden fields before postback and retrieve the new values from there.

Comment: hey @user35....    the hidden field thing worked great, simple and now a direct path to updating the database on the postback.  thanks for the help!